# PHP built-in server - run in project root but access public folder

Tags: php, localhost

Say i Have the following project structure

```
├───project
│   ├───private
│   └───public
```

If I run `php -S localhost:8000` from `public`, I only get partial functionality.
If I run the same command from `project`, I have to manually add `/public` to the `localhost:8000` url.

Is there a way to use `php -S` from the project root and not have to add `public` manually?

Comment: No, you have to use a webserver with rewriting functionalities. The PHP server is for development purposes only

Comment: Elaborate more. How you would want URLs for private and public folders?

Comment: Maybe `php -S localhost:8000 -t /path/to/project/public/` ?

Comment: You could also set `include_path` in php.ini or set it in the command line, not sure exactly what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP manual for [Built-in web server](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) says ...

> If a PHP file is given on the command line when the web server is started it is treated as a "router" script. The script is run at the start of each HTTP request. If this script returns false, then the requested resource is returned as-is. Otherwise the script's output is returned to the browser.

You could create a `router.php` that requires the files in both directories file. Otherwise you probably need to use an autoloader.

The new command would be `php -S localhost:8000 router.php`.